# Alternative method for acquiring a Tracker in an Android InputMethodService

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

[My previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36458222/getdefaulttracker-from-a-class-that-extends-inputmethodservice) didn't receive much attention and I'm assuming that's because there's no real answer to it.

Detailed in the question, I'm trying to track user input within a class that extends `InputMethodService`. Sadly, Google Analytics does not provide a way to acquire a `Tracker` from within `InputMethodService`. I provide code that details the normal way of doing so in the question linked above.

Is anybody aware of a non-standard method for acquiring a `Tracker` in an Android application?`

Comment: If you are just concerned about getting Tracker in SubClass of InputMethodService, you can simply have a getter method for Tracker and do `((AnalyticsApplication) getApplicationContext()).getTracker();`..
Hope I answered what you were expecting..