# Add google analytics tracker to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-analytics

I am integrating google analytics to my app across all activities and fragments. 
Referring to [developer docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#activity-or-fragment), I could easily associate trackers to activities.

```
AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
```

But how do I obtain a shared Tracker instance with fragment? Each fragment represents a screen view.

Also, how do I obtain the time spent on each ScreenName that is configured?

Comment: Currently I have put the tracker obtained from MainActivity in global scope and used the instance in necessary fragments, but I am looking for a better practice.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36458222/getdefaulttracker-from-a-class-that-extends-inputmethodservice)

Answer (score 0):

In your application class, write this..

```
private Tracker mTracker;

/**
 * Gets the default {@link Tracker} for this {@link Application}.
 *
 * @return tracker
 */
synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
    if (mTracker == null) {
        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        // To enable debug logging use: adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
        mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker);
    }
    return mTracker;
}

public void trackEvent(String category, String action, String label) {
    Tracker traker = getDefaultTracker();
    // Build and send an Event.
    traker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder().setCategory(category).setAction(action).setLabel(label).build());
}
```

Now in each fragment you want to track event, then do this

```
 YourApplicationClass.getInstance().trackEvent("Category", "Action", "Label");
```

For sending your screen name from fragment, do this

```
   YourApplcationClass application = (YourApplcationClass) getActivity().getApplication();
    mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
    mTracker.setScreenName("FragmentName");
```

Comment: I have implemented something similar. Was curious if I can avoid this boiler code through some methods provided by google sdk.